# Como fazer para "Esconder" Informação ao inspecionar elementos HTML

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando em uma ideia e, apesar de eu não trabalhar com informações sensíveis, gostaria de saber como omitir do usuário caso fosse necessário. Por exemplo, acessei dois sites e, em ambos, ao inspecionar os elementos, as informações "processadas" estavam sendo exibidas assim:

[image: Vejam que]

Notem que entre as *tags* existe um pequeno retângulo com `[...]` dentro, enquanto que ao inspecionar as *tags* que eu desenvolvi, o navegador me mostra o texto em Html.

Comment: E por qual motivo você precisa ocultar dados do DOM?

Comment: Resumo: não há como. Se quer ocultar, não envie essa informação e proteja de outra forma.

Comment: "um pequeno retângulo com [...] dentro" .... isso não significa nada, apenas clicar na fecha inicial que a tag mosta todo o conteúdo interno.